# Remove only one matching element from two arrays

Tags: php

```
$array1 = array(1.99);
$array2 = array(1.99, 1.99, 2.99);
```

I want to remove only one matching element of $array1, from $array2.

so, What I want is:

```
1.99
2.99
```

Ive tried `array_diff()`, which will take out both of the `1.99` and leave me with only `2.99`.

Comment: Make a foreach and compare values. array1 __always__ has 1 element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact `array_search` will only return one matching element from the target array, and use it to remove that from `$array2`:

```
$array1 = array(1.99);
$array2 = array(1.99, 1.99, 2.99);

foreach ($array1 as $remove) {
  unset($array2[array_search($remove, $array2)]);
}
```

If `$array1` can contain elements that aren't present in `$array2` then you'll need to add a check that the result of `array_search` is not false.

Answer (score 0):

First merge the two arrays the find unique elements .Try `array_merge()` and `array_unique()`

```
<?php
$array1 = array(1.99);
$array2 = array(1.99, 1.99, 2.99);

print_r(array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2)));

?>
```

Comment: But if element of $array1 doesn't exist in $array2 it will be pushed in it with array_merge()

Answer (score 0):

I did similar to @iainn:

```
foreach($array1 as $k=>$v){
    if(in_array($v, $array2)){
        unset($array1[$k]);
        break;  
    }
}
```